# Send multiple *.mat files via PUT or POST request in Matlab

Tags: html, matlab, http, http-post, httprequest

I would like to send multiple MAT-files via a POST or PUT request to a server in Matlab, but I have problems building the RequestMessage. Can anyone help me with this task? I'm new to Matlab and would be grateful for any help.
My code produces the following error message, :

*Error using RequestMessage*
*Expected RequestLine to be one of these types:*

*matlab.net.http.RequestLine*

*Instead its type was string.*

Here is my code:

```
import matlab.net.http.*
import matlab.net.http.field.*
import matlab.net.*

% Define train and test directories
train_dir = "./data/train";
test_dir = "./data/test";

% Get all train files in train_dir
train = dir(fullfile(train_dir, "*.mat"));
train_files = [];
for k = 1:length(train)
    full_file = fullfile(train_dir, train(k).name);
    train_files = [train_files; full_file];
end

% Get all test files in test_dir
test = dir(fullfile(test_dir, "*.mat"));
test_files = [];
for k = 1:length(test)
    full_file = fullfile(test_dir, test(k).name);
    test_files = [test_files; full_file];
end

% Create POST request
provider = MultipartFormProvider(...
    "train_files", FileProvider(train_files),...
    "test_files", FileProvider(test_files));

% Request message and response
request = RequestMessage("PUT", [], provider);
response = request.send("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/data_upload");
```

I already implemented the file transfer with a html site, which works well. Hope that helps to describe my problem. Here the html template:

```
<title>Upload train and test files</title>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2>Train files</h2>
    <p><input type="file" name="train_files" multiple="" accept=".mat">
    <h2>Test files</h2>
    <p><input type="file" name="test_files" multiple="" accept=".mat">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload train AND test">
    </p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: Found a solution on my own. Finally the origin of the error message were the double quotes around PUT, it has to be single quotes.
Here my working solution, hope it may help someone with the same problem:

```
% Create POST request
% File providers
file_provider_train = FileProvider(train_files);
file_provider_test = FileProvider(test_files);

% Multipart form provider
provider= MultipartFormProvider(...
    "train_files", file_provider_train, ...
    "test_files", file_provider_test);

% Request message and response
request = RequestMessage('POST', [], provider);
response = request.send("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/data_upload");
```